# iPython: Unable to export data to CSV

Tags: jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I have searched a multiple articles, but unable to get iPython (Python 2.7) to export data to a CSV, and I do not receive an error message to troubleshoot the specific problem, and when I include "print(new_links)" I obtain the desired output; thus, this issue is printing to the csv.

Any suggestions on next steps are much appreciated !
Thanks!

```
import csv
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

url = 'http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/list'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
new_links = []
for link_node in doc.iterdescendants('a'):
    try:
        new_links.append(link_node.attrib['href'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

cdc_part1 = open("cdc_part1.csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(cdc_part1, dialect='excel')
wr.writerow(new_links)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the `new_links` is a list of lists.

If so and `wr.writerow(new_links)` is still not working, you can try:

```
for row in new_links:
    wr.writerow(row)
```

I would also check the open statement's file path and mode. Check if you can get it to work with 'w'.

Comment: Corrected the Path and added "for row in new_links:", and this did the trick.  Thanks !